# Search column for text from a Word file and display the cell adjacent

Tags: vba, excel

Using VBA for work, I already have code that analyses a Word file, picks out the aspects it needs and converts it to an Excel format.

We assign tasks to people in a Word file, the file and code is set in a way that it recognizes who is responsible for the task, e.g. `Joe`. We have many employees and I want to be able to get the script to search whatever name it has picked out from a list in one column, find the cell in which the name is and then display the data in the cell directly adjacent to it.

Currently the code has many people manually placed in there in loops i.e. if `Joe` present then display `usernameJoe`.

I have the usernames and names split in a table on the workbook structured as:

```
Name        Username
Joe A       ajoe
Jack B      bjack 
John C      cjohn
...              ...
```

While my code works when placed individually in loops:

```
Joe responsible?
            If InStr(current_action.resp, "Joe") <> 0 Then


                ' assigning to online account
                current_action.resp = "ajoe"
```

creating 85 loops is a long process and in an always changing work place too long-winded.

The picked-out name is known as `current_action.resp` in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an array and loop on it :

```
Sub test_Mugiwara_Luffy()

Dim PersonS(), _
    i As Long, _
    NameS() As String

ReDim PersonS(1 To 85, 1 To 2)

PersonS(1, 1) = "Joe A"
PersonS(2, 1) = "Jack B"
PersonS(3, 1) = "John C"
'....

For i = LBound(PersonS, 1) To UBound(PersonS, 1)
    If Len(PersonS(i, 1)) >= 5 And InStr(1, PersonS(i, 1), " ") Then
        NameS = Split(PersonS(i, 1), " ")
        PersonS(i, 2) = LCase(Left(NameS(UBound(NameS)), 1) & NameS(LBound(NameS)))
    Else
    End If
    If InStr(current_action.resp, PersonS(i, 1)) Then
        ' assigning to online account
        current_action.resp = PersonS(i, 2)
    Else
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks R3uK this worked a treat! I was thinking of doing this! Thanks

Comment: @mugiwara Glad I could help! Take a minute to take the tour and see how to accept answers and use votes : http://stackoverflow.com/tour